# Sample frequency in ALSA in C

Tags: c, alsa

I have a program that records 5sec of  the audio values  using the ALSA lib , here is the code :

```
#define ALSA_PCM_NEW_HW_PARAMS_API
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long loops;
  int rc;
  int size;
  snd_pcm_t *handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
  unsigned int val;
  int dir,z=0;
  snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
  signed short *buffer;
  FILE*  inp = NULL;
  FILE*  inp2 =NULL;
  inp = fopen("values","wb+");
  inp2 = fopen("Values2","w+");

  int fd = open("v",O_WRONLY);
  /* Open PCM device for recording (capture). */
  rc = snd_pcm_open(&handle, "default",
                    SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, 
            "unable to open pcm device: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Allocate a hardware parameters object. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

  /* Fill it in with default values. */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_any(handle, params);

  /* Set the desired hardware parameters. */

  /* Interleaved mode */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(handle, params,
                      SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);

  /* Signed 16-bit little-endian format */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(handle, params,
                              SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);

  /* Two channels (stereo) */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(handle, params,1);

  /* Sample frequency */
  val = 96000;
  //val2 = val;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate(handle, params, 
                                  val, &dir);
  printf(" %d \n", val);

  /* Set period size to 32 frames. */
  frames = 32;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, 
                              params, &frames, &dir);

  /* Write the parameters to the driver */
  rc = snd_pcm_hw_params(handle, params);
  if (rc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "unable to set hw parameters: %s\n",
            snd_strerror(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Use a buffer large enough to hold one period */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params,
                                      &frames, &dir);
  size = frames * 1; /* 2 bytes/sample, 1 channels */
  buffer = (signed short*) malloc(size);

  /* We want to loop for 5 seconds */
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params,
                                         &val, &dir);
  loops = 5000000 / val;

  while (loops > 0) {
    loops--;
    rc = snd_pcm_readi(handle, buffer, frames);


    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(signed short),size,inp);
    for(z =0; z<size;z++)
        fprintf(inp2,"%lf\n",buffer[z]/1.0);


  }

  snd_pcm_drain(handle);
  snd_pcm_close(handle);
  printf(" buffer");
  free(buffer);
  fclose(inp);
    fclose(inp2);
  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm using the function `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate` to set an exact value for `fs` but I get this warning :

```
     warning: passing argument 4 of ‘snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
                                   val, &dir);
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h:54:0,
                 from capture.c:4:
/usr/include/alsa/pcm.h:743:5: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 int snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate(snd_pcm_t *pcm, snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params, unsigned int val, int dir);
```

I've check the [documentation](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m___h_w___params.html#ga29cd2571738847813af1489043d1af5a) the parameter type should be correct, but more interesting is that after the running the program,  I get another warring or error :

```
*** Error in `./out': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000002462d90 ***
```

Aborted (core dumped)

this don't show up when I use :

```
   size = frames * 1; to 

size = frames * 2;
```

an the result is just wrong, I tried to use a lower sample frequency but it didn't help.
when use : `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near`  the sample freuqency changes to 192000 and the result is than correct, I would really use the first function so I get to know what sample freuqcy I'm using.

any idea how I can do it, or why do I get those warrings ?

Comment: regarding the warning, compiler is right, you're passing the address of `dir` which is of type `int *`.

Comment: According to the documentation you linked to the fourth parameter should be an `int`, not an `int *`.

Comment: ups thanks, this solve the first warning !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the warning, compiler is right, you're passing the address of `dir` which is of type `int *`.

Comment: @Engine: I think you ought to be allocating your buffer with `buffer = (signed short*) malloc(size * sizeof(signed short));`

Comment: @Engine: How are you calling snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate() now? Are you passing a correct value for the 4th parameter. Looking at the documentation, I think the valid values are -1, 0, and 1.

Comment: I put 0 , which works fine for recording the only problem that I got now is when I put fs = 96000 I get 480448  values for 5sec which not correct  !

Comment: actually it's case with different values for fs, I  don't get the exact number of samples as I should !

Comment: I might be wrong but I think the read loop is not at all accurate. Maybe there's a more accurate way of doing it? I think you should check on that. Reading further on the documentation, it says that the value from `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time` is `approximate maximum period duration in us`.

Comment: actually, you are reading the right number of samples.  However, your writing to two files in the read loop.  That produces major delays, so samples are getting overwritten.  One effect of increasing the sample size is there is a little more time for those two writes to files.  Also, double buffering would greatly help.  As was stated above, the allocation of the buffer is incorrect as malloc (by default) only allocates bytes and you actually need to allocate twice as many to allow for unsigned short.

Comment: @user3629249  thanks for comment but I've tried to use only one write function but the result is the same I get more samples if I chose a higher frequency I have to learn more about the buffer and period etc in ALSA maybe that would help ! thanks